# fatal error: 'geos_c.h' file not found on Mac m1

Tags: homebrew, dependency-management, apple-m1, geos

I have already installed `geos` library using `brew install geos`, but I'm still getting following error on mac M1.

```
./geos.h:1:10: fatal error: 'geos_c.h' file not found
#include <geos_c.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Have you `-I<path_to_goes_headers>` on the compile line?

Comment: I am not actually directly compiling this file. This error is occurring when I run a make command on large project I am working at my organization. The make command runs following. `go mod download`, `go mod vendor`, `GO111MODULE=on go get github.com/golang/mock/mockgen@v1.5.0`, `go generate ./...` and finally `go test -cover ./...`. Should I provide any other information. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Hi @RuchitPatel were you able to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 5):

I believe it is because brew doesn't install the header packages. You can build from source.
This is what I did to solve it:

```
brew install wget

wget http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.3.8.tar.bz2

tar -xvf geos-3.3.8.tar.bz2
```

And run `./configure`, `make`, and `sudo make install` in the extracted directory.